# Handling one to many relationship in solr

Tags: solr

I have a requirement where I have to handle one to many relationship in SOLR.
Say , an entity Person can have multiple names(first name, last name, name type). Now the problem with this is that if I make first name , last name & name type as multi- valued field in my schema.xml it won't help.Because I will not be able figure out which first name will be associated to which last name and which name type.
What I want is if I have a person say P1 with 2 names [name_type1,firstName1,lastName1] & [name_type2,firstName2,lastName2].
Now if I do a full text search firstName1 then I should get back P1.
Is there any way to handling this use case in SOLR?

Comment: What are your search requirements.  Do you just want a free-text search for names, or do you need to be able to search for specific name types e.g. [specific name type]='John Smith'?

Comment: It could be possible by use of grouping in solr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your documents looked like the following:

```
name.first.[type] = John
name.last.[type] = Smith
```

which can be defined as dynamic fields:

```
<dynamicField name="name.first.*" type="text" indexed="true"  stored="true" />
<dynamicField name="name.last.*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

and have [copy field definitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields) in your config:

```
<copyField source="name.first.*" dest="text" maxChars="256" />
<copyField source="name.last.*" dest="text" maxChars="256" />
```

which will copy all your names into a 'text' field which can be searched on.

With this structure, if the field values are stored (versus just indexed) then it'll be possible to reconstruct all the names from a person document.