# Storing 1-to-Many Content tags in solr

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr,

My application has a mapping between `Movies` and `Interests`

I basically have `movie_id -> Interest_1 -> Interest_2 -> Interest_3 etc etc.`

eg.  `Interstellar -> Technology -> People -> Science`

Each Movie can have 'N' number of interests.

Originally, This exists in MySQL, and i'm importing these to Solr.

How should i store `Movie` -> `Interest` data into Solr and also be able to **query it by interest_name**

Comment: please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482222/handling-one-to-many-relationship-in-solr

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti There is no need for a copyField in this case, as all interests come from the same table/field as I understand. CopyField would be interesting for information from different fields to aggregate into one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a multivalued text field in your movie schema for the interest, with the values you want to query in the end (interest_name). With that you are able to query for movies having one or more given interests.